# How to lose the focus of a edittext when "done" button in the soft keyboard is pressed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have 7 edittext boxes in my xml. I'm using the OnFocusChangeListener to read the value from edittext and i'm using that value for my calculation.I want to make my edittext to lose its focus when i click on the done button in the soft keyboard.so that i can get the value in the edittext.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Call `clearFocus` method of `EditText` to lose focus when done button is clicked from soft-keyboard. do it as:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //Clear focus here from edittext
             editText.clearFocus();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

and also add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` in edittext xml

Comment: clearFocus may not work if there's no other focusable view or if the same view is the first from the top that can take focus. Notes from the doc:
**_When a View clears focus the framework is trying to give focus to the first focusable View from the top. Hence, if this View is the first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give focus to this view._**

Comment: Using `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` won't clear focus even if you call `editText.clearFocus();`

Make sure to use `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: This clears the focus, but overrides standard behaviour to hide the keyboard.

Comment: Although this is an ancient post, it's still relevant. In the old, old days Android supported real, flip-out, keyboards. The soft keyboards on Android were crap, so it was natural to develop a whole load of apis around hard keyboards. The sirens' song of setKeyListener etc. is still very powerful. But this post made me see the light. When I switched to something based on the code above, it worked like a charm. And now it's 2022!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes across this question wondering how they could **unfocus everything at once** in their activity, they can set the **focus on the parent layout** (or any layout for that matter).

```
findViewById(R.id.myLayout).requestFocus();
```

Comment: Not working for me, the first EditText gets the focus after the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more complete answer

```
//  This will change the ‘RETURN’ button in your the EditText’s soft keyboard to a ‘DONE’ button.
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
//  Use the InputMethodManager to close the soft keyboard
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //Clear focus here from edittext
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin, it worked for me:

```
main.clearFocus()
```

main is a root ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of ρяσѕρєя K's answer:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        editText.clearFocus()
    }
    false
}
```