# Editview press softkey Return, lose focus AND hide keyboard, how?

Tags: android, textview

I'm working on an Android app and I've got 2 editviews and a label. The user can enter 2 values and the label shows some calculation using input from the editviews. What I want is the following;

1. user enters either value with soft-keyboard
2. user presses "Return" softkey
3. editview should lose focus
4. the soft-keyboard should disappear
5. textview label should be recalculated

Now, the v.clearFocus only seems to works when there is another widget that can can get focus(?), so I've also added a **dummie zero-pixel layout** that can 'steal' the focus from the first editview. The Return key works now, but when the user switches focus from edit1 to edit2 by simply tapping then **HideKeyboard() crashes**. I've tried checking if inputMethodManager==null but that didn't help.

This all feels like I'm hacking to trick Android into doing some common UI behaviour, so I can't help but think that I'm overlooking something here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Btw I know this is similar to this question: [How to lose the focus of a edittext when "done" button in the soft keyboard is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981740/how-to-lose-the-focus-of-a-edittext-when-done-button-in-the-soft-keyboard-is-p)
But I've tried that and it doesn't work.

So my layout xml is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Dummy control item so that first textview can lose focus -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTest1"
        android:layout_width="250px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" >

    </EditText>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTest2"
        android:layout_width="250px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" >
    </EditText>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test123" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the source is this:

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab2_weight);

        EditText testedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTest1);

        testedit.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        testedit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        

            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    //Clear focus here from edittext
                    Log.d("test app", "v.clearFocus only works when there are other controls that can get focus(?)");
                    v.clearFocus();
                }
            return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus == false) {
            Log.d("unitconverter", "onFocusChange hasFocus == false");
            // update textview label
            TextView bla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            bla.setText(String.format("%s + %s", (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTest1)).getText()), (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTest2)).getText()))); 
            // hide keyboard
            hideSoftKeyboard();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the softkeyboard automatically disappear when enter is pressed?

Comment: Well, when I use an EditText usercontrol and set the android:imeOptions="actionDone" property then the Return-key hides the keyboard.

However then the editview will still have the focus. I need the focus change because I use the onFocusChange event to refresh the label to reflect the user changes.

Comment: you can capture the key for actionDone and then refresh it there. Then you would not need the work around above